# Aggregating one factor based on another in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a `R` `data.table` object `DT` as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

DT <- movies[movies$mpaa %in% c("NC-17", "PG", "PG-13", "R"), c("rating", "title", "mpaa")]
setDT(DT)
setnames(DT, colnames(DT), c("Gp", "ID", "FACTOR"))
DT[, FACTOR := droplevels(FACTOR)]
DT[, Gp := as.numeric(as.factor(Gp))]
setkey(DT, ID)
DT <- unique(DT)

DT
      Gp                       ID FACTOR
   1: 43                  $windle      R
   2: 61             'A' gai waak  PG-13
   3: 62    'A' gai waak juk jaap  PG-13
   4: 39                  'R Xmas      R
   5: 38       'Til There Was You  PG-13
  ---                                   
4899: 57                  Zuotian      R
4900: 27 Zyosyuu syukeininn Maria      R
4901: 57                 eXistenZ      R
4902: 45                      xXx  PG-13
4903: 29  xXx: State of the Union  PG-13
```

I am trying to aggregate the data in the `FACTOR` column according to elements in column `Gp`. I have been able to achieve it as follows.

```
k <- vector("list", max(DT$Gp))
for (i in 1:max(DT$Gp)) {
  names(k)[i] <- i
  k[[i]] <- DT[Gp == i, as.vector(table(FACTOR))]
}
k <- lapply(k, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))
k <- rbindlist(k)
setnames(k, old = colnames(k), new = c("NC-17", "PG", "PG-13", "R"))
k$Gp <- row.names(k)
setcolorder(k, c("Gp","NC-17", "PG", "PG-13", "R"))

head(k)
   Gp NC-17 PG PG-13 R
1:  1     0  0     0 2
2:  2     0  0     0 1
3:  3     0  0     0 2
4:  4     0  0     0 1
5:  5     0  0     0 2
6:  6     0  0     0 3
```

For each level of `Gp` I want to get the number of records in each level of `FACTOR`. How to get the desired result `k` more elegantly using `data.table` alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `as.list(table(FACTOR))` within each group of `Gp`:

```
DT[, as.list(table(FACTOR)), by = Gp]
```

This gives the result:

```
    Gp NC-17 PG PG-13  R
 1: 43     1  8    26 79
 2: 61     2  9    22 77
 3: 62     0  7    18 63
 4: 39     0 17    24 52
 5: 38     1 14    13 77
 6: 57     1 11    23 72
 7: 48     0 16    29 78
...
```

(To order them by `Gp` as they are in your example output, you could change this to `DT[order(Gp), as.list(table(FACTOR)), by = Gp]`).

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using `dcast` for this:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.4
dcast.data.table(DT, Gp ~ FACTOR, fun.aggregate = length)
```

Or from the [current devel, v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) (and future versions), we can directly use `dcast()`:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
dcast(DT, Gp ~ FACTOR, fun.aggregate = length)
```

`as.list()` is a S3 generic and will get quite slow with more groups (due to time taken for dispatching the right method for each group). And `table()` is another slow function.

`dcast()` automatically sorts the result by`Gp` column as well.

---

Here's a big-enough benchmark to highlight the difference:

```
set.seed(1L)
bmark = data.table(Gp = sample(1e5, 1e7, TRUE), 
                   FACTOR = sample(levels(DT$FACTOR), 1e7, TRUE))
print(object.size(bmark), units="Mb")
# 114.4 Mb

system.time(ans1 <- dcast(bmark, Gp ~ FACTOR, fun.aggregate = length))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.998   0.026   1.030 

system.time(ans2 <- bmark[, as.list(table(FACTOR)), by=Gp])
#    user  system elapsed 
#  14.666   0.141  15.078 

identical(ans1, setkey(ans2, Gp))
# [1] TRUE
```

The data size is ~114MB, which is not really huge, with the speed up being ~15x.